# How to count the colony using opencv java?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm having a problem on counting the accurate colony in this plate. I would really appreciate if someone could help me on getting the right algorithm for this.

[Here's the original picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHkbw.jpg)

First,  I found the container/plate then use this following code.:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, result, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
Imgproc.medianBlur(result, result, 7);
Core.inRange(result, new Scalar(15,2,120), new Scalar(150, 255, 180), result);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(result, result, new Size(3, 3), 0);
Imgproc.threshold(result,result, -1, 255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Imgproc.dilate(result, result, element);        
Imgproc.findContours (result, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
Imgproc.cvtColor(result, result, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    for (int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Rect r=Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));

          if(r.area() > 3000000)
           {

              MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(i).toArray() );

               double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02;
               Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

                //Convert back to MatOfPoint
                MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );
                Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

                Core.rectangle(result, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1,8, 0); 

            } 
          else
          {
              colonyCount++;
              Imgproc.drawContours(result,contours,i,new Scalar(255,0,0),Core.FILLED);
           }
```

System.out.println("Colony count:"+colonyCount);
The result image is this. [The result image is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R7PG.jpg)

I want to eliminate the borders of the plate and the noise as well around the plate. Kindly help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: This question is near to computer science problem, not SO problem.

Comment: I am new to image processing. It's my first time to use opencv. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.